# How to disable Shadows or alter required Components of Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use `<AppBar>` component of Material UI. But, it generates shadows. I searched for some solution and came across to change use the
`createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider` and set default shadow to

`const theme = createMuiTheme({
  shadows: ["none"]
});`

By doing this it removes shadows from every element I use.But , I want to use shadows for buttons and other components..

So, How can I change the shadow property of  component only??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the component has the appropriate props you can use the 'props' property in the object passed to createMuiTheme. For example, if I want to remove box shadows ("elevation") from **all** buttons in my app, I can use the following code:

```
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
    props: {
      MuiButton: {
        disableElevation: true
     }
    }
});

// more code...
return <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>
```

See the 'Default Props' section in the Material UI docs: https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/

This works by adding that prop as a default option to all buttons. The nice thing is that if you occasionally want to add a property back, you can just add it to the component itself:

```
// add box-shadow to this one button
<Button elevation={5}>Hooray, Box Shadow!</Button>
```

If the component doesn't take the relevant prop, then you can use the overrides:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme = ({
    overrides: {
      MuiButtonGroup: {
        // the contained class has the box-shadow css
        contained: {
          boxShadow: 'none'
        }
      }
    }
})
```

Unfortunately the Material UI spec is all over the place, so what works for one component won't necessarily work for the next!

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `override` within Theme and specify component as well. In your case you need to use `MuiAppBar`, which means that properties under it will effect only the `AppBar` component.
Here is an example.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiAppBar: {
      boxShadow: 'none'
    }
  }
});
```